# Accessing fish functions from perl

Tags: shell, function, fish

In bash I can do:

```
foo() { echo bar; }
export -f foo
perl -e 'system "bash -c foo"'
```

I can also access the function definition:

```
perl -e 'print "foo".$ENV{"BASH_FUNC_foo%%"}'
```

How do I do the same in `fish`?

Edit:

With this I can get the function definition:

```
functions -n | perl -pe 's/,/\n/g' | while read d; functions $d; end
```

If I can put that in an enviroment variable accessible from Perl, I ought to be able to execute that before executing the command. So similar to:

```
setenv funcdefs (functions -n | perl -pe 's/,/\n/g' | while read d; functions $d; end)
perl -e 'system($ENV{"funcdefs"},"foo")'
```

But it seems setting `funcdefs` ignores the newlines: $ENV{"funcdefs"} is one horribly long line.

The odd part is that it seems `fish` *does* support environment variables containing newlines:

```
setenv newline 'foo
bar'
echo "$newline"
```

Can I encourage `fish` to put the output from the command into a variable, but keeping the newlines?

Comment: Variable contains newline worked fine for me in fish 2.1.0. `fish` disable word splitting by default.

Comment: @cuonglm I tested with 2.1.1. This still does not work: `setenv quux (echo foo;echo bar); echo "$quux"`. It works beautifully in Bash: `quux=$(echo foo;echo bar); echo "$quux"`

Comment: I'm not sure about that. I tried enter newline literally, set var 'foo\nbar'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugly as hell, but works:

```
function foo
  echo bar;
end

setenv funcdefs (functions -n | perl -pe 's/,/\n/g' | while read d; functions $d; end|perl -pe 's/\n/\001/')
perl -e '$ENV{"funcdefs"}=~s/\001/\n/g;system ("fish", "-c", $ENV{funcdefs}."foo")'
```

Answer (score 2):

In `fish`, you can use [funcsave](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#funcsave) to save function definition across fish session:

```
$ function qwerty
    echo qwerty
end
$ funcsave qwerty
$ fish -c qwerty
qwerty
$ perl -e 'system "fish -c qwerty"'
qwerty
```

Comment: Assume it is a function that I will never use again, can I avoid saving it?

Comment: @OleTange: AFAIK, you can't. You can use [functions](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#functions) `-e funcname` to erase the function after using it.

Comment: Would that not violate the first design principle for fish? http://fishshell.com/docs/current/design.html

Comment: @OleTange: I think no. `funcsave` can do job that `export -f` can do and it more powerful than that since when it can work across all fish session. It can be considered the same as what you do in `.bashrc`

Comment: I respectfully disagree that forcing a function to be globally visible is more powerful than being able to keep it locally visible: I often create a throw-away function called `doit`. If I create a function in two different windows I do not want one definition to overwrite the other.