# Define function in fish, use it with watch

Tags: function, fish, watch

I want to define a function, and call that function every n seconds. As an example:

```
function h
    echo hello
end
```

Calling `h` works:

```
david@f5 ~> h
hello
```

But when using watch, it doesn't...

```
watch -n 60 "h"
```

...and I get:

```
Every 60.0s: h                                      f5: Wed Oct 10 21:04:15 2018

sh: 1: h: not found
```

How can I run `watch` in fish, with the function I've just defined?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another way would be to [save the function](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/204521/117549), then ask `watch` to invoke fish:

```
bash$ fish
fish$ function h
    echo hello
end
fish$ funcsave h
fish-or-bash$ watch -n 60 "fish -c h"
```

`funcsave` saves the named function definition into a file in the path `~/.config/fish/functions/`, so `~/.config/fish/function/h.fish` in the above case.

Comment: Much easier than the other solution, but still complicated. Perhaps I'll just reimplement watch within fish........

Answer (score 3):

There is no easy way.  By default `watch` uses `/bin/sh` to run commands but takes `-x`:

```
   -x, --exec
          Pass  command  to  exec(2)  instead  of  sh -c which reduces           
          the need to use extra quoting to get the desired effect.
```

However, nothing will not work with `fish` because `h` function is not
exported to environment:

```
$ watch -n 5 --exec  fish -c h
Every 5.0s: fish -c h                                                                                                                                                                 comp: Wed Oct 10 21:30:14 2018

fish: Unknown command 'h'
fish:
h
^
```

In `bash` you could export a function to environment with `export -f`
and use it inside `watch` like this:

```
$ h1 () {
> echo hi
> }
$ type h1
h1 is a function
h1 ()
{
    echo hi
}
$ export -f h1
$ watch -n 60 bash -c h1
Every 60.0s: bash -c h1                                                                                                                                                               comp: Wed Oct 10 21:29:22 2018

hi
```

If you use `fish` you can create a wrapper script and call it with `watch`:

```
$ cat stuff.sh
#!/usr/bin/env fish

function h
    date
end

h

$ watch -n5 ./stuff.sh
```

Also note that `fish` has `.` and `source` so you can define function
in another file and be able to re-use it in other scripts like that:

```
$ cat function
function h
    echo hi
end
$ cat call.sh
#!/usr/bin/env fish

. function

h
$ watch ./call.sh
```

Comment: I like the solution with the wrapper script best... but yet the best solution is when everything would work within fish. I can hack a function in fish and then use watch on that function within fish.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I did it! It does the job, but I still wish `fish` had something native. I choose the name `blotch` so it doesn't interfere with bash's `watch`.

```
function blotch
    # 2018-10-10
    # 
    # This is like the watch command of bash,
    # but re-implemented in fish.
    # 
    # It takes two arguments:
    #   n: the interval in seconds
    #   fun: a fish function
    # 
    # Therefore, it is always used as:
    # 
    #   blotch n fun
    # 
    # Take note that you should start fish with
    # 
    #   sudo fish
    #   
    # before doing anything with blotch that
    # requires administrator privileges.

    set time (string split " " -- $argv)[1]
    set command (string split " " -- $argv)[2]
    while true
        sleep $time
        eval $command
    end
end
```

And save the function for later use.

```
funcsave blotch
```

Comment: that's a pretty ugly way to parse the arguments. I would use `function blotch -a time command` to instruct the command to assign the first 2 args to the "time" and "command" local variables. Then the function body can just contain the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Another quite easy way would be...

```
function fonzie
    echo "This is Fonzie!"
end

while true
    fonzie
    sleep 10
end
```